# When to modify and secure variables passed to a URL?

Tags: php, security, url, xss

With all the talk of SQL Injection...I am sort of wary as to when I need to secure URL variables. Is it necessary to secure variables that will not be used in a database, but used only in code or would it still be possible to inject malicious content. For example:

```
<?php
$format = $_GET['format'];
//other potentially vulnerable code? (no SQL)
echo date($format);
?>
```

Is this in need of additional security or does this fall under circumstances where that is not necessary? If the later is true, what should one look for to know it is necessary to secure variables?

As a complete side-note not exactly worthy of it's own question thread...what is the difference between => and -> ?

Comment: In this code you have html injection, more commonly known as XSS.

Comment: I see...does this mean the use of strip_tags() or htmlspecialchars() is the only necessary measure?

Comment: Please read http://kunststube.net/escapism for an introduction to the problem domain.

Comment: this `=>` is used with arrays and this `->` is used with object and methods...

Comment: Is => used in foreach also? Are they interchangeable or will that result in a parse error?